# what should I use to pass parameters? List / Array / Object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list

presaying i'm still a newbie.
I've this situation to solve. I know it's something very very easy. But I just started to study C# world.

I need to pass to a function an associative array of x elements.

I need to pass some data like `data1=een&data2=twee&data3=drie&data4=fier`.

Then my questions are:

1) how can i declare my function?

```
private void myFoo(List<List<string>> data){}
private void myFoo(string[] data){}
```

2) how can I loop on a list of a string list? something like this -i know it's not correct-

3) how can I create my array?

Comment: Will your value for x be set, or does it vary?

Comment: @Paddy i did not understand what you mean

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option would be to use a `Dictionary<string,string>`.  This would allow you to have keyed values passed through your functions.

```
private void myFoo(Dictionary<string,string> data)
{}
```

Build it as:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dict.Add("data1", "een");
dict.Add("data2", "twee");
```

Fetch via:

```
var value = dict["data1"];  // You can also use TryGetValue, etc.
```

Comment: I was about to propose the same.

Comment: `System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary` would be more appropriate is what I feel

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That class isn't more appropriate - it was a better option before generics (if you're using .NET 1.1), but post-generics, those classes are really ones that are better unused.

Comment: part 2) of OP's question - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx shows you how you loop on the dictionary using 'foreach' under 'Remarks'. You will get a KeyValue Pair where Key = data1 and Value = een

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Why?  It has less features than a `Dictionary`.  It's only purpose was to have a strongly typed `HashTable` back before generics existed.  Once .NET 2.0 came out it really only needed to exist for backward compatibility.  There is no reason to ever use it in new development at this point.

Comment: ok, i will try the dictionary or the string dictionary. thank you very much.

Comment: great the KeyValuePair solution @topomorto